# problem while connecting with remote server in vs 2005

Tags: c#

I'm doing a remote application in .NET 2005,while I'm connecting the client with remote server in the local machine it works fine, when it comes to a remote machine it raises an exception:

**"A remote side security requirement was not fulfilled during authentication. Try increasing the ProtectionLevel and/or ImpersonationLevel."**

How do I handle this, why is the exception getting raised, and is there any problem with rights on the remote machine.

I did a sample remote application, I put the server side coding to one of the machines on 
our network, and I ran the client program from my machine, while trying to connect to the server the client raises an exception:

**"A remote side security requirement was not fulfilled during authentication. Try increasing the ProtectionLevel and/or ImpersonationLevel."**

I'm using Visual Studio .NET 2005 (.NET 2.0 framework).

Comment: How are you connecting? Why arer you connecting? "When it comes to remote machine..." what does this mean?

Comment: .net 2005? may be .net 2.0, and SQL Server 2005. Be more exactly.

Comment: What OS are you working on? It may be UAC getting in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while registering the channel ,i put **false for ensure secure property** and it works.

```
channel.registerchannel(8080,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution here, but I did a quick google search.

Try to disable "Use Simple File Sharing" under Tool -> Folder Options -> View in Windows Explorer.